# My Ember "if" is not calling the associated function why?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this if statement in my html file:

```
{{#if statusIsCreated}}
     <button class="btn btn-success" {{action toggleProp}}>Edit</button>
{{/if}}
```

and this on my controller:

```
    statusIsCreated: function () {
       if (this.get('model').get('status') === 'Created') {
            return true;    
       }
},
```

What this is supposed to do is when this template is called it will check if the value of the property status is 'Created' and if so a button will be shown.

I tried debugging it and noticed it's not even getting to the if statement on the controller... any idea why?

Comment: You cannot bind a function in handle bar template. You must use computed property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `statusIsCreated` a computed property:

```
statusIsCreated: function () {
   if (this.get('model').get('status') === 'Created') {
        return true;    
   }
}.property('model.status')
```

Comment: I had already tried something like this and now tried it again but it's still not even getting to the if statement on the controller ...

Comment: This should work. Check this condition and return for falsy condition as well

Comment: I put  {{else}} TEST! on the html and it's showing, but I'm also sure that status has the value Created (because when I put {{status}} right before the if it shows Created) so maybe something is not working correctly. Any idea what?

Comment: Check if you have any space in the status property. put a break point in controller file on the if condition. Check why this condition is failing.